# DistanceTo - Getting Low Numbers

Tags: android

I am currently trying to work out the speed of a user.

However, I'd had trouble trying to get the distance between two locations.

When I used distanceTo and printed it, the result was a very low number, 0.01~ m/s, and there was no difference between moving and not moving.

I think there is a problem with the updating location values, because it used to be stuck on 0, but then it stuck on 3.5 m/s, then 0.5.

(The code's speed value is now just the distance value to display the core problem, which is distanceTo. The speed value will later be divided by time differences between the two locations, one the distanceTo problem is fixed..)

This is my current relevant code. If you wish to see full code, please refer to:
http://pastebin.com/sUPGTAfq

```
protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //Build resources if null
        if (settings == null) {
            settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        }

        Boolean RequestingLU = settings.getBoolean("RequestingLU", true);
        if (!RequestingLU) {
            StoppedMessage();
        }
        if (RequestingLU) {
            if (mLocationClient == null)
            {
                buildLocationClient();
            }
            mLocationClient.connect();

        }

    }

public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You have connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mLocationClient, mLocationSettingsRequest
            );
    result.setResultCallback(ViewingWindow.this);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        OldLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mLocationClient);
    }
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Location Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (settings == null) {
        settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    }

    double speed = OldLocation.distanceTo(location);

    OldLocation = location;
}
```

Comment: `speed = OldLocation.distanceTo(location);` for me speed is distance **per time**

Comment: *read the comment in brackets please.*